# CA1404 - despite the statement is preceded by return clause, CA2000 - despite no further reference usage

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I'd like to understand why two CA warnings appears in my code:

***CA2000** Dispose objects before losing scope In method 'ImpersonateValidUser(string, string, string, LogOnType, LogOnProvider, ImpersonationLevel)', call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'tempWindowsIdentity' before all references to it are out of scope.*

***CA1404** Call GetLastError immediately after P/Invoke    Method 'ImpersonateValidUser(string, string, string, LogOnType, LogOnProvider, ImpersonationLevel)' called GetLastWin32Error but the immediately preceding call to 'IDisposable.Dispose()' is not a P/Invoke statement. Move the call to GetLastWin32Error so that it immediately follows the relevant platform invoke call.*

Below there is simplified code sample, with lines commented exactly in the place of warnings appearance:

```
private static void Impersonate(string userName, string domain, string password, LogOnType logonType, LogOnProvider logonProvider, ImpersonationLevel impersonationLevel)
{
    var token = IntPtr.Zero;
    var tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
    if (NativeMethods.RevertToSelf())
    {
        if (NativeMethods.LogonUser(userName, domain, password, (int)logonType, (int)logonProvider, ref token) != 0)
        {
            if (NativeMethods.DuplicateToken(token, (int)impersonationLevel, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
            {
                /* CA2000 */ using (var tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate))
                {
                    _impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /* CA1404 */ var e = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    throw new Win32Exception(e);
}
```

CA2000 - the object `tempWindowsIdentity` is not used after the `using()` statement completes, so why this warning ?

CA1404 - `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` is always invoked just after native methods. Even when there is situation `using()` statement is invoked earlier, the `return` clause appears, so `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` is not then invoked, so why this warning ?

Comment: Are you sure the posted code produces the CA2000 warning?

Comment: It is a bug in FxCop, it doesn't handle the scope properly.  Note how it *does* see the Dispose() call but attached it to the wrong statement.  Don't let an FxCop bug spoil your code, flip the ignore bit.

Comment: @Hans Passant: thanks, I don't know what is the source of your knowledge, but it's quite intense

Answer (score 0):

This code should fix those CA warnings... not really elegant... but Code Analysis never produces elegant code.

```
private static void Impersonate(string userName, string domain, string password, LogOnType logonType, LogOnProvider logonProvider, ImpersonationLevel impersonationLevel)
{
    if (!NativeMethods.RevertToSelf())
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

    IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;

    if (NativeMethods.LogonUser(userName, domain, password, (int)logonType, (int)logonProvider, ref token) == 0)
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

    IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

    if (NativeMethods.DuplicateToken(token, (int)impersonationLevel, ref tokenDuplicate) == 0)
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;

    try
    {
        tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
        _impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (tempPort != null)
        {
            tempWindowsIdentity.Dispose();
            tempWindowsIdentity = null;
        }
    }
}
```

For what concerns CA1404, the error code raised by a faulty API call could be meanwhile overwritten by internal calls from other managed class library methods if you don't catch it immediatly.
In CA2000, WindowsIdentity in your approach is created but the object is not disposed before all references to the object are out of the scope; doing that you don't allow exceptions to be raised at the fault point.

Comment: Hi, I know how to find workaround, I'm just curious what is wrong with the approach I've shown.

Answer (score 0):

I believe CA2000 occurs as you are violating the following part of the rule which implies you are creating a disposable object inside `using` statement;

> Returning a disposable object requires that the object is constructed
>   in a try/finally block outside a using block.

Also CA1404 occurs as you are not calling `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();` immediately after native calls. Try to call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();` in each `if` statement as the first item in the code.

Answer (score -1):

We solved CA1404 the following way. The cause was that "!= 0" is the immediate call after LogonUser() or DuplicateToken().

```
private static void Impersonate(string userName, string domain, string password, LogOnType logonType, LogOnProvider logonProvider, ImpersonationLevel impersonationLevel)
{
    var token = IntPtr.Zero;
    var tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
    if (NativeMethods.RevertToSelf())
    {
        var logonUserSuccessful = NativeMethods.LogonUser(userName, domain, password, (int) logonType, (int) logonProvider, ref token);
        var e = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();  // call before comparison against 0 to avoid CA1404
        if (logonUserSuccessful != 0)
        {
            var duplicateTokenSuccessful = NativeMethods.DuplicateToken(token, (int) impersonationLevel, ref tokenDuplicate);
            e = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();  // call before comparison against 0 to avoid CA1404
            if (duplicateTokenSuccessful != 0)
            {
                /* CA2000 */
                using (var tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate))
                {
                    _impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    throw new Win32Exception(e);
}
```

Comment: And what happens when exception is thrown from  `DuplicateToken` (or from any other subsequent native method)? This code simply wipes it out.